# Invisible button area on both sides my html button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created a normal button component for my react project. The button is work fine. but there are invisible area on both sides of button. That area height is same to the button. but the width is 100% of the screen in both sides. I did not add those. Those areas are also works as the button. How could this happen?
Also in the button area, mouse pointer is not changing to a hand icon. but in the invisible button area mouse pointer turns into hand icon. Do anyone know how to make button area only as the button or what is the wrong in my work

[If the explanation is not clear, Click and see this image. Red colour covered area completely works as the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asxxF.png)

here is my button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button , makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core";
import './styles/MainButton.css';

export default function MC_MainButton(props) {

const {text, onClick}=props

  return (    
    <>
      <div className="border">
        <Button class="mainButton" onClick={onClick} variant="contained" >{text}</Button>   
      </div> 
    </>
  );
}
```

here is my MainButton.css

```
.mainButton { 
  min-width:157px; 
  min-height:48px ; 
  border-radius:12px;  
  background-color: #f6cbc1;
  padding-top: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px #00000029;
  color: #555050;
  font-family: normal normal bold 45px/52px Calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight : bold ;
  opacity: 1;
  /* padding-top: ; */
  
}

.border{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: could you please add what does 'other' prop contain? that may change the behavior if it passes styles, etc.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. there are no any other props. I added it thinking it would be necessary. But it's not. now I'm removed it and updated the question. the problem is still same. Do you know what the the wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

It's `className`, not `class` in react

Comment: I fixed that. The problem still same. Also I tried that className adding using another `div` tag. It is also useless. Is there any solution or another way to customized button size and colours in react. (I used material-ui)